# best path for how to learn rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to the rails . And I want to start lernig rails. 
Please help me to find currect path and also material on same

Comment: Try to build an app by following the book "https://www.railstutorial.org/book"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a plethora of resources out there that you can find by doing a simple search.

I haven't delved too deep into Ruby on Rails but the resources that have proven to be helpful for me in the past have been:

[Ruby on Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book)

[Codecademy - Ruby on Rails](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-rails)

Those should be able to give you a good start with the fundamentals.

Happy programming! :)

Comment: I agree with you. Michael Hartl's Rails tutorial is very helpful for a beginner. It is a good source to learn.

Comment: Is it necessary to lern ruby befor starting with rails

Comment: Following those above tutorials, I wouldn't say that it is completely necessary but having a basic understanding of the language won't hurt either. You'll learn some along the way